# Position of Google Javascript on a page

Tags: javascript, html

I just fixed a spacing bug on a HTML page I have inherited - and I worked out in the end that on that particular page this being at the top of the page was pushing the layout out;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
```

I understand that it's good sometimes to place javascript right at the end of the Doc, but in this case Im wondering if moving this will cause any problems - it certainly fixes the layout ! Thanks

Comment: can you show us how it breaks the layout?  in what browsers?  what is the markup?

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the markup up - the adwords post solves the q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the explanation here
http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115794#

The script MUST be as close to the `</body>` tag as possible

Comment: Hi, Had a look - and it seems to be that particular javascript line that pushes things out - even when in the header. Putting this at the end of the document before the end body sorts the problem, It was more I was wondering if by moving that script to the end, it would cause problems with the how the conversion.js integrates with the page

Comment: can you please answer Bob's question? Browser version, platform, markup? There is no reason this script would interfere with positioning, especially not in the head of a page since it does not render anything or import a stylesheet or such

Comment: Erm. Sorry let me retract that. Stand alone I do not see this script adding anything to the page, but it can, so I would need to see how it reacts when it is fed with parameters most likely set before it in a script tag

Comment: Changed my answer. Found the explanation in the FAQ at the adwords help page